# Facebook Example code from SDK does not work for me, gives unknown error

Tags: facebook

I made an app and used the example.php code for it. I didnt change it in any way. It looks alright, but if i click on the login button it gives me a weird error:

```
An error occurred with siapa wajah akatsukimu. Please try again later.
```

I would post the source, but there's no point you can find it online at the sdk. I didnt change anything. Has anyone ever had this problem logging in on the example code?

Is there a good reason as to why I would get this issue?

Comment: Can you post the source or at least a link to the specific example code you're referring to? Kind of difficult to help you out otherwise.

Comment: did u replace the APP_ID and APP_SECRET with your own?

Comment: Make sure you have changed the APP_ID and APP_SECRET and also make sure that you are giving the correct 'return_url' !!

Answer (score 0):

Check  your app setting, ID and Secret.  But if you are having trouble use the example below.
It has a full explanation, demo and source code.
http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-3-0-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/

It is for the PHP SDK (3.0) but if you look through the blog there is a JSexample as well.